# Jump starting a motorcycle behind a fuse? (slow blow atc fuse?)

Tags: amperage, fuses

I have a motorcycle with an SAE 12v 10ga lead for charging that I'd also like to occasionally jump-start the motorcycle with, I need about 90amps for about 1 second, which is *fine* for the 10ga wire, but not fine for the 30amp inline ATC fuse.

Do they make slow-blow fuses for ATC that would allow momentarily 90amps, but break on sustained 30amps?  I don't want to risk of fire and I don't want to bypass the fuse entirely.

Must I go Direct?

**Edit**, I found "Flosser Micro FMM Mcase Fuse" that are slow-blow 30Amp fuses, but cannot find an inline holder, that may be the answer I need but still unable to source the parts.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No kick-start pedal?

Comment: lol, no 2300cc Rocket 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer was to replace the battery so I don't have to design something to jump it each time I want to ride it.

Direct wire also allowed it to be jumped but increased the danger of fire if the POS (not exposed) terminal was grounded.